# Troubles with if statement on github actions

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

[image]

I need to trigger the 'Slack Notification About Invalid Case Ids -- Stage 2' job only if INVALID_CASE_IDS_ARRAY is not empty.

So I've created the 'Stage 1' job to get the boolean variable for triggering my 'Stage 2' job, but it just skips the 'Stage 2' job.

I've already tried

```
if: ${{ steps.invalididslackreport.outputs.invalididpresent == 'true' }}
if: ${{ steps.invalididslackreport.outputs.invalididpresent == 'false' }}
if: contains(${{ steps.invalididslackreport.outputs.invalididpresent }}, 'true')
```

It doesn't work too.
Help me, please.

I'm 100% sure that variable has a 'true' value and if statement in the 'Stage 1' runs perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All inputs and outputs are strings..  so you need to do string comparison like == 'true'.

You can also use toJson and fromJson like this

```
echo ::set-output name=foo::${{ toJSON(false) }}
if: fromJSON(steps.bar.outputs.foo)
```

Comment: thx, but with
if: ${{ steps.invalididslackreport.outputs.invalididpresent == 'true' }}
or
if: ${{ steps.invalididslackreport.outputs.invalididpresent == 'false' }}
it doesn't work, idk why, 
I will try toJson

Comment: Odd, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Same=( It just skipped Stage 2, but the variable is true